# My color of a link doesnt change?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I check everything about my code but I dont found the problem why my link are not white. I watch the relevant post about it to check if someone ask this question and if I had the same mistake. But sadly no.

Thats my HTML Code

```css
#topleiste {
  background-color: #42587E;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#topleiste li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 5px 1px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topleiste">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.de/">ARD Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.de/">Nachrichten</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.de/">Sport</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.de/">Börse</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.de/">Ratgeber</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.de/">Wissen</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.de/">Kultur</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.de/">Kinder</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.de/">ARD Intern</a></li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: What are looking for your link is already white. can you explain little more what you exactly want ?

Comment: try changing `a:link` to `a`

Comment: Clear your browsing history for that site or change the site to something you haven't been to.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your CSS where `a:link` won’t target the link if you already visited it before(I’m guessing you had been in Google before), instead, change it to simply `a`. Tell me how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably because the links change color when they have been visited. To prevent this you can add the css:

```
a:visited {
  color: white
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#topleiste li a {
   color: #fff;
}
```

or in your case:

```
#topleiste li a, #topleiste li a:hover, #topleiste li a:active, #topleiste li a:focus {
   color: #fff;
}
```